# Can't silence notification on Android API29

Tags: android, android-notifications

Need to silence a notification that is shown by a foreground service. To silence the notification I have used many suggested solution from SO. But nothing seems to silence the annoying notification sound. It is silenced on SDK25. But on SDK 29 emulator it is not silenced. What can be the solution?

Code:

```
//service

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    createNotificationChannel()

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0, notificationIntent, 0
    )
    val notification: Notification =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("app_name")
            .setContentText("Updating database.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
    startForeground(1, notification)

    thread() {
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        stopSelf()
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = SettingsHelper.KEY_NOTIFICATION_channel_name_service
        val description = SettingsHelper.KEY_NOTIFICATION_CH_ID_SERVICE
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            SettingsHelper.KEY_NOTIFICATION_CH_ID,
            name,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        )
        channel.description = description
        channel.setSound(null, null)

        val manager = getSystemService(
            NotificationManager::class.java
        )

        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post all of the code you use for creating the notification?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I have updated with all service code to reproduce. It plays notification sound.

Comment: Have you tried to use empty sound file instead of null?

Comment: @Rifat did you try my solution?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS When I used NotificationCompat.Builder I had not to use `setSilent()` it was silent by default. I used it anyway to be safe. Thank you for your suggestion and effort.

Comment: setSilent didn't work then?

Comment: setSilent could be a solution. But I could not confirm it as notification with NotificationCompat.Builder was silent even without it on SDK29 emulator. However SDK30 emulator plays a small ding sound with or without `setSilent(T)`

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [`setSilent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setSilent(boolean))  from NotificationCompat.Builder

> If true, silences this instance of the notification, regardless of the sounds or vibrations set on the notification or notification channel. If false, then the normal sound and vibration logic applies. Defaults to false.

Note, that if you are changing notification settings, I recommend you to uninstall and re-install the app everytime since it might not be updated the settings you set in the new run.